# Ruby on Rails Less source maps and the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, less, asset-pipeline, source-maps

I'm currently using the less-rails gem in a Ruby on Rails application that I'm building. I would like some way to debug my Less css files in Chrome by way of source maps (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/css-preprocessors) Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Not an answer but in case you haven't seen these yet... (1) a gem for source maps with sass [sass-rails-source-maps](https://github.com/vhyza/sass-rails-source-maps) and (2) a gist for an initializer for coffeescript source maps [source_maps.rb](https://gist.github.com/alexspeller/3730452)

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the most convenient way to solve the problem: to abandon the assets pipeline and less-rails. change to [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) or [blendid](https://github.com/vigetlabs/blendid) with [gulp-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less)+[gulp-less-sourcemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less-sourcemap). This will take time to configure, but as my practice shows, the loss of time more than pays off with features like life edit, very fast compilation, and of course - sourcemaps.

In fact, I personally did not use *less* in such a bundle, but the implementation of *sass* is very convenient. I think that with *less* it could be the same

Answer (score -3):

You can use pry to debug in rails. So, whereever you are using your css in the haml or html you can write something like -binding.pry( if its haml). Pry is used for debugging ruby code but you can also use it in your haml(view) using -.

https://github.com/pry/pry

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not what I was asking for.